# E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate in Docker Ubuntu

Tags: java, docker, ubuntu, dockerfile

I want to install java8 in Ubuntu image on docker. so I inserted follow codes in dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
RUN  apt-get update 
CMD ["echo", "apt-get update done ..."]
RUN apt-get -qq install -y wget
CMD ["echo", "wget Done ..."]
RUN apt-get install -y software-properties-common 
CMD ["echo","apt-get install -y software-properties-common"]
RUN add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/java 
CMD ["echo","add-apt-repository. ..."]
RUN  apt-get update 
RUN  apt-get -qq upgrade
CMD ["echo", "apt-get update done ..."]
# add webupd8 repository
RUN \
    wget https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu/gpg && \
    apt-key add gpg &&\
    apt-get update  &&\
    echo "===> add webupd8 repository..."  && \
    echo "deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list  && \
    echo "deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu trusty main" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/webupd8team-java.list  && \
    apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv-keys EEA14886  && \
    apt-get update
RUN echo "===> install Java"  && \
  apt-get -qq upgrade && \
  echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | debconf-set-selections  && \
  echo debconf shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 seen true | debconf-set-selections  && \
   apt-get update &&\
  DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive  apt-get install -f oracle-java8-installer
```

but give me this error ```Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package oracle-java8-installer is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer' has no installation candidate ```

Comment: Use ubuntu 16.04instead. It has openjdk8-jdk

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I use an image that forces the use of Oracle-Java8; so I force that install it.

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 support is ending this month.

Comment: see, In docker file, I put `Ubuntu: latest`.  My problem this error `E: Package 'oracle-java8-installer'`. I edit my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is an image in Docker Hub that Ubuntu+java8.
so can use this repository ([enter link description here](https://hub.docker.com/r/2chat/ubuntu-java8/tags))